# how to read column from text with javascript

Tags: javascript, file, parsing

i tries to understand but without success, how to read from the file all cities name into array in java script?
that is the file:
http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt
pleas add code example. 
thank a lot.

Comment: Please you add your unsuccessful code first.

Answer (score 0):

1. You load the file content in to a variable with ajax (using local copy of file and jquery)

   ```
   $.get('city_list.txt', function(data) {
   ```
2. then you split the file with linebreaks in to a variable

   ```
   var lines = data.split(/\n/);
   ```
3. loop the array of lines and split then with your column delimiter (tab)

   ```
   lines[i] = lines[i].split(/\t/);
   ```